# como puedo crear una barra de busqueda en php y sql

Tags: php, sql

tengo un problema, como pueden ver en el codigo quiero crear la opcion de mostrar en una tabla html los datos personales que corresponden a una cedula, esto lo hago a traves de una barra de busqueda. quiero hacer que si alguien introduce los datos en la barra, solo se muestren esos datos, sino que muestre todos los datos de la tabla. el codigo me muestra bien la informacion cuando nadie ingresa ningun dato en la barra de busqueda pero al ingresar el numero de cedula que se quiere buscar en especifico no realiza nada y sigue mostrando lo mismo.

```
   <?php 

        $servidor="localhost";
        $usuario="root";
        $password="17122001";
        $db="sistema";

        $conexion= new mysqli($servidor,$usuario,$password,$db);

        if ($conexion->connect_error) {
            die("conexion fallida" . $conexion->connect_error);
        };

        if (isset($_GET['borrar'])){
        if ($_GET['borrar'] == $_GET['borrar'] ) {
            $sql="DELETE FROM rock WHERE cedula='$_GET[borrar]'"; 
            $conexion->query($sql);
        }
        };

            if (isset($_GET['busqueda'])){
                $sql="SELECT FROM rock WHERE cedula='$_GET[busqueda]'"; 
                $conexion->query($sql);
            }
            else{
                $sql="SELECT * FROM rock";
                $resultado=$conexion->query($sql);
            }

    
    ?>
        <table>
        <caption>Rock Sinfonico</caption>

        <div class="busqueda">
        <form action="rock.php" method="POST">          
            <input  type="search" name="busqueda" size="10" placeholder="Buscar...">                
            <input type="submit" name="busqueda" placeholder="Buscar" value="Buscar" required>
        </form>
        </div>

        <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>Cedula</th>
                <th>Direccion</th>
                <th>Telefono</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody>

            <?php
                $mRows="";
                    while ($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
                            $mRows="<tr>
                                        <td>$row[nombre]</td>
                                        <td>$row[apellido]</td>
                                        <td>$row[cedula]</td>
                                        <td>$row[direccion]</td>
                                        <td>$row[telefono]</td>
                                        <td><a href=\"rock.php?borrar=$row[cedula]\" method=\"GET\" >Borrar</a></td>
                                    </tr>";
                                    echo $mRows;
                    }
                    
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<?php
    $conexion->close();
?>
```

Comment: Tienes `$conexion->query($sql);`, te falta asignar a la variable: `$resultado = $conexion->query($sql);`

Comment: donde pongo la variable?

Comment: Busca en el código dónde falta ponerla... ¡justo ahí la pones!